# MongoDB $addToSet equivalent in CockroachDB

Tags: cockroachdb

As the title suggests, is there an operator similar to MongoDB's `$addToSet` in CockroachDB? I want to append a value to an array if it's not present.

I browsed the docs but didn't find an `$addToSet` operator.

Answer (score 0):

The `array_append` function should work for this case, see this doc: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/array.html#using-the-array_append-function

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two functions to do this with arrays. Either of these should work:

```sql
array_append(array_remove(myArray, newElement), newElement)
IF(array_position(myArray,newElement) IS NULL, array_append(myArray,newElement), myArray)
```

If what you're representing should never contain duplicates, you might be better off using a JSON object type than an array type, since their keys are automatically unique. Here's an example:

```sql
create table unique_groups(id int primary key, vals jsonb default '{}');

insert into unique_groups values (1, '{}'), (2, '{"a": true}');

-- Add "b" to each set
update unique_groups set vals = jsonb_set(vals, '{b}', 'true') where true;

select * from unique_groups;
  id |         vals
-----+-----------------------
   1 | {"b": true}
   2 | {"a": true, "b": true}

-- Add "a" to each set
update unique_groups set vals = jsonb_set(vals, '{a}', 'true') where true;

select * from unique_groups;
  id |          vals
-----+-------------------------
   1 | {"a": true, "b": true}
   2 | {"a": true, "b": true}
```